# Cannot add new instance to generic list in generic class. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, constraints

I have the following generic class:

```
public class MessageProcesser<T> where T : Message
```

Inside the code I have the following attribute:

```
private readonly BlockingCollection<T> _messages;
```

When I try to do this I get an error (and as T is a Message it should be possible):

```
_messages.Add(new Message(MessageType.Stop));
```

What's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need generics for this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a collection of messages. Message can't be T, because T may have been inherited.

try

```
private readonly BlockingCollection<Message> _messages;
```

Comment: +1 Indeed, to say it another way, although the OP states `where T : Message`. `T` might be `DerivedMessage : Message` so adding `Message` to a `BlockingCollection<DerivedMessage>` is invalid. However, adding `DerivedMessage` to a `BlockingCollection<Message>` is valid and perhaps what the OP was *trying* do to.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. The MessageProcessor should process Messages, not T.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler error is the fact that you assume `T` is always `Message`. `T` could be a *more derived* type, like `DerivedMessage : Message`. This would make your collection `BlockingCollection<DerivedMessage>`, trying to set an instance of `Message` into this would be invalid.

If you want to contain a list of all messages regardless of type, all you need to do is have:

```
private readonly BlockingCollection<Message> _messages;
```

And completely remove the use of generics.  You can then store `Message` types and any type that derives from `Message`.

If you want to have `MessageProcessor<T>` handle any message and store the correct, *relevant* type, you could always use the `new()` constraint that forces the type to have a **public parameterless** constructor:

```
public class MessageProcesser<T> where T : Message, new()
```

Then you can perhaps do this:

```
var message = new T(); 
message.MessageType = MessageType.Stop;
_messages.Add(message);
```

You **cannot** constrain on constructors with arguments, so your current constructor use would not be supportable. A way around this is to pass a `MessageFactory` to the `MessageProcessor` and *abstract* creation responsibility to the factory.

Comment: I could accept your answer too ... the other one was higher on the page :P

Comment: @SoMoS Entirely up to you, I'm not fussed :-) I was only trying to complement his answer with further detail.